# How to setup a dev branch in git?

Tags: git, branch

A bunch of us are working on a shared repository and using git for collaboration and version control.
We actually use gitolite in the backend.
We felt the need to have a dev branch so that the production branch is not affected whenever two people want to work on something together.
Any pointers on how to setup a dev branch and merge it back to master if required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally you do the following to branch and merge.

To make a dev [branch](http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/lab_24.html):

```
git checkout -b dev
```

To [merge master onto dev](http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/lab_28.html):

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
git hist --all
```

Comment: Also if user A on comp A.local wants to work with user B on comp B.local on the "dev" branch, while gitolite is on gitmach.local ? For the master branch, A's doing `git push origin master` and B's running `git pull` works. What should one do for the "dev" branch ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question. Are you asking for how to push and pull the dev branch? See [Pulling changes](http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/lab_44.html#main_content) and [Pushing a change](http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/lab_48.html#main_content).